# Elastic Search 2.0 search query in main object and nested object

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-2.0

This is my model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Nested]
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }        
}
```

Mapping:

```
mappings: {
  student: {
    properties: {
      firstName: {
        type: "string"
      },
      id: {
        type: "integer"
      },
      lastName: {
        type: "string"
      },
      subjects: {
        type: "nested",
        properties: {
          id: {
            type: "integer"
          },
          subjectName: {
            type: "string"
          }
       } 
    }
 }
}
}
```

To search inside the nested object (Subject) I use following code and it returns the values correctly.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Student>(s => s    
.Query(q => q
    .Nested(n => n
        .Path(p => p.VolunteerTasks)
        .Query(nq => nq.Match(m => m
            .Query(searchText).Field("subjects.subjectName"))))));
 return searchResponse.Documents;
```

But I want to search with the same searchText for `student.firstName`, `student.lastName` and `subjects.subjectName`.
How can I do that?

Comment: any luck? please comment if you need further info

Comment: Yes, the bellow answer helps me to find a solution. But now I have a another issue.

I need to enter exact word for searchText to get the result. As an example SubjectName - "Science and technology"

If I search with technology, It returns the record. But If search with techno, It did not return the record. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Thanks Opster Elasticsearch Ninja. The answer given by jaspreet chahal helps me to solve my issue.
I have asked a separete question for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61629848/elastic-search-2-0-search-like-query/61630390#61630390
Can you check this and help me to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a should clause with a match query on first name and last name 
and a nested query on subject name. You cannot club nested and non nested query in a single match or multi-match query

```
var searchResponse = _elasticClient.Search<AssociateProfile>(s => s
                     .Query(q => q
                                 .Bool(b=>b
                                             .Should(
                                                        sh => sh.Match(m => m.Query(searchText).Field("student.firstName")),
                                                        sh => sh.Match(m => m.Query(searchText).Field("student.lastName")),
                                                         sh => sh.Nested(n => n
                                                                               .Path(p => p.VolunteerTasks)                                                                                           .Query(nq => nq.Match(m => m                                                                                           .Query(searchText).Field("subjects.subjectName")))
                                                                                    )

                                                                   )
                                                    )
                                              ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing answer in form of REST API, which you can convert it into c# format, As I am not familiar with its syntax and it would be helpful for people who are not looking for language-specific answers.

**Tested this with your sample data and below is the working solution**.

**Index Def**

```
{
    "student": {
        "properties": {
            "firstName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "lastName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "subjects": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "subjectName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample doc which doesn't have `opster` either `subject` and `firstname` **

```
{
    "firstName": "Isuru",
    "lastName": "foo",
    "id": 1,
    "subjects": [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "subjectName": "math"
        },
        {
            "id": 101,
            "subjectName": "opster"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Index another doc which doesn't have `opster` in any subject name**

```
{
    "firstName": "opster",
    "lastName": "tel aviv",
    "id": 1,
    "subjects": [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "subjectName": "math"
        },
        {
            "id": 101,
            "subjectName": "science"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Search query, please change `must` to `should` according to your requirements**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [    --> note
                {
                    "match": {
                        "firstName": "opster"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "subjects",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [   -->note
                                    {
                                        "match": {
                                            "subjects.subjectName": "opster"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "nested",
                "_type": "student",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.39103588,
                "_source": {
                    "firstName": "opster",
                    "lastName": "tel aviv",
                    "id": 1,
                    "subjects": [
                        {
                            "id": 100,
                            "subjectName": "math"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 101,
                            "subjectName": "science"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "nested",
                "_type": "student",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.39103588,
                "_source": {
                    "firstName": "Isuru",
                    "lastName": "foo",
                    "id": 1,
                    "subjects": [
                        {
                            "id": 100,
                            "subjectName": "math"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 101,
                            "subjectName": "opster"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment from the OP, Adding an answer which provides the partial match. like if the document contains `Science and technology` and searching for `techno` should also come.
Note using the custom [edge-n-gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) analyzer for achieving this requirement.

**Index def**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete", 
        "search_analyzer": "standard" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index sample doc**

```
{
    "title" : "Science and technology"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query" :{
        "match" :{
            "title" :"techno"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "edge",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.44104567,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Science and technology"
                }
            }
        ]
```